# Plesk subdomain creation "limitations are exceeded"

Tags: subdomain, plesk

When trying to create a subdomain in **Plesk 11.5**, i have the following message :

> An error occurred during domain creation: Unable to accept the template: the following limitations are exceeded.
>   Description                       Requested Allowed 
>   Retain web and traffic statistics 3         12

Ok, I already created something like 50 subdomains… but eh, i do what i want !

Here is my command (yeah, i replaced [SUBDOMAIN] and [DOMAIN] by what i want… mysubdomain.domain.tld) :

> /usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain --create [SUBDOMAIN] -domain [DOMAIN] -www-root /subdomains/[SUBDOMAIN]/httpdocs

I need to create something like 600 subdomains by parsing a csv file with a shell script i wrote… (it doesn't work either with user-friendly web interface).

Everything's fine except this limitation… I tried many different things in Plesk web admin, and tried to get manual of subdomain.

Comment: Could you use a wildcard match then in the included config check if a directory exists for the subdomain otherwise return a 404? (This would only work if each of the subdomains is set up in the same fashion. ie similar features, logging path, etc.)

Comment: Hey, I like the idea but :
- ok for the wildcard, *.mydomain.com. Until now, i know how to manage that…
- but what about this matching thing ? in my vhost.conf or something like that ?

Comment: and hmmmm… something strange is happening… wildcard is ok (but every subdomains are pointing to httpdocs for now) BUT some work, some not !! If I try stuff1.mydomain.tld, or stuff2.mydomain.tld… 404… but stuff3.mydomain.tld is working ! Though one of the 3 has a dedicated folder !!

Comment: Yes, I was thinking you might modify vhost.conf. I forget if DocumentRoot is configured there or higher up in the primary file. Weird about the inconsistent domain handling. Perhaps this page could help? https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains_for_multi_site_under_Plesk_Control_Panel

Comment: Ok… i needed to restart Apache, cause Plesk doesn't seem to do it by itself. Now the mystery of this matching things, which is very interesting for me, and could avoid me a lot of work and subdomains management remains the same !

Comment: This is the idea I was thinking of based on your 600+ subdomains: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to increase "Retain web and traffic statistics" limit in subscription's properties or in Service plan properties?